# PHP -MYSQL: Will the database import more than 40,000 rows?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I'm developing a web application for a Autoparts store.

I'm making an algorithm to import at CSV file which contains more or less 40,000 products (rows). It is the first time I'm gonna work with such a large file. So I have some questions before I proceed.

1) Will MySQL take the time and import every single row or will it auto-crash and throw an error for a time limit or something?

2) I'm using PDO for all related with database stuff. What if the database is importing all these thousands of rows and suddenly the web application user closes the browser, shuts the computer down or something?

Will the uploaded file finish importing in the server? or will the transaction interrupt?

In that case, I'd want a rollback.

Thank you for enlightening me.

Comment: 40,000 really is not that many records. you should be reading your csv file a line at a time to avoid memory issues with fgets() or something similar. quitting the browser should not change anything with the sql transaction. No rollback, backup the database and restore if it fails.

Comment: You could have a try with [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/load-data.html) and read your CSV file into a staging table first.

Comment: Actually the CSV file has been converted into an associative array. So, by the time I'm ready to create the INSERT query, I'm working with an associative array. It's not a CSV file anymore. But the array contains those 40,000 rows.

Comment: @JuanBonnett You'd have an easier time if it was still CSV.

Comment: I'm gonna study that LOAD DATA INFILE thing and see what can I do with it. Instaed of converting the file into an array, I would better import the data there then. Thanks

Comment: Seems like I'll be forced to create the INSERT query from the array because the CSV file contains some columns that are not in the actual table and must be omited. The array alows me to choose what indexes or keys I want to insert :/

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can insert large no of records than 40,000.

just check these conugurations.

```
max_allowed_packet 
bulk_insert_buffer_size
key_buffer_size
```

you can refer this
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: Please try and link to the documentation relating to the most recent version of MySQL. 5.1 is woefully out of date.